# Cat5 wiring in my home

Tags: cat5

I have problem with cat5 cabling

First I ran a length of cable 30 metres to my bedroom 1 and and connected  both ends to a wall sockets internally using my punch down tool, both ends look fine. I also ran a cable from bedroom 1 to bedroom 2 so my son can use same internet connection , i then parallel connected my cables in bedroom 1 against using punch down tool using same colours all the way through. I ran a Ethernet cable from modem to first wall socket close to it then at bedroom end used another Ethernet cable to connect pc, it wouldn't connect to pc so I disconnected bedroom 2 cable from bedroom 1 socket. I connected bedroom 1 to pc and it worked, but how do I connect bedroom 2 (obviously cat 5 cable bedroom 1 to 2 is in place)
As soon as I connect one wire from bedroom2 I loose Internet connection!

Comment: Hi Mike. Please check the FAQ, especially the part where it mentions 'it is not about anything in a home setting`. Your question may be on-topic in another place, but please check their FAQ first. (e.g. Superuser.com).

Comment: Belongs either over in Superuser or DIY and some sort of circuit diagram would be really helpful. Word problems get really annoying.

Comment: Ethernet just doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 1):

> i then parallel connected my cables in bedroom 1 against using punch down tool using same colours all the way through.

You need a [network switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch). Ethernet can't share the physical layer in the way that you are describing. Since you aren't just trying to network multiple computers, but also share Internet access, a router with integrated switch would be ideal.